# C Wide characters - how to use them?

Tags: c, character, wchar-t

I'm able to output a single character using this code:

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>

main(){

setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");
wchar_t a = L'Ö';
putwchar(a);

}
```

How can I adapt the code to output a string?

Something like

```
wchar_t *a = L"ÖÜÄöüä";
wprinf("%ls", a);
```

Comment: What's wrong with wprintf(L"%ls", a)? Doesn't it work for you?

Comment: Ehmm.. thanks you just answered my question. I'm missing the L in my code.

Comment: That said, wchar isn't good for much. It only works for 16-bit Unicode, and isn't that portable. UTF-8 (combined with a library for internationalization heavy lifting, such as iconv or ICU) is almost always a better choice.

Comment: `wchar_t` is 32 bits on most Unix-like systems, but 16 bits on Windows.

Comment: Are you going to accept one of the answers, or is there still something unclear?

Answer (score 2):

```
wprintf(L"%ls", str)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit tricky, you have to know what your internal `wchar_t`s mean. ([See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300804/wchars-encodings-standards-and-portability) for a little discussion.) Basically you should communicate with the environment via `mbstowcs`/`wcstombs`, and with data with known encoding via `iconv` (converting from and to WCHAR_T).

(The exception here is Windows, where you can't really communicate with the environment meaningfully, but you can access it in a wide version directly with Windows API functions, and you can write wide strings directly into message boxes etc.)

That said, once you have your internal wide string, you can convert it to the environment's multibyte string with `wcstombs`, or you can just use `printf("%ls", mywstr);` which performs the conversion for you. Just don't forget to call `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "")` at the very beginning of your program.