# What is the locale of UTF-8?

Tags: c, facebook-graph-api, encoding, utf-8, locale

I am getting an XML file from the Facebook API with the data:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<fql_query_response xmlns="api.facebook.com/1.0/"; xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"; list="true"> 
    <user> 
        <uid>100000022063315</uid> 
        <name>0xD7 0x99 0xD7 0x95 0xD7 0x97 0xD7 0x90 0xD7 0x99 0x20 0xD7 0x95 0xD7 0x9B 0xD7 0x98 0xD7 0xA8</name> 
    </user>
</fql_query_response>
```

I want to translate the UTF-8 to `wchar_t`. I am trying to do so with `mbstowcs` but apparently I need to know what locale to set. Is there a standard locale for Facebook? or for UTF-8?

Comment: UTF-8 doesn't have a "locale". It is just an [encoding](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr17/) for [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) (maps Unicode codepoints onto one or more bytes, often for transmission) -- what "locale" is Unicode?

Comment: Any locale ending in ".utf8" will do, e.g. "en_US.utf8". Say `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "en_US.utf8");` before you do `mbsrtowcs` and it should work. Alternatively use iconv going from UTF8 to WCHAR_T.

Comment: I would set it so that wchar_t strings are UTF-16 (or UTF-32 depending)

Comment: @Kerrek SB: That's a Linux locale. On Windows, [If you provide a code page like UTF-7 or UTF-8, `setlocale` will fail, returning `NULL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x99tb11d.aspx)

Comment: @Martin: You cannot control the _result_ of `mbstowcs`. It's just some implementation-defined fixed-width string. @MSalters. Good point. Use iconv (from UTF8 to WCHAR_T), as I suggest below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To translate data that's not associated with the user's configured locale, but rather an explicitly specified encoding, you should use `iconv`, not `mbsrtowcs`. You don't need `setlocale` at all for this.

Answer (score 4):

As @pst notes, the terminology here is a bit wrong. "Locale" is used sometimes to refer to which ANSI code page is used to represent international text when unicode is not available.

Read Joel Spolsky's fantastic ["The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)"](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Now, to answer your question, if you need to convert UTF-8 encoded text to UTF-16 (or what in Windows is commonly called "wide char") you can use a function such as [MultiByteToWideChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  with the parameter `CP_UTF8`

Comment: Yes, im running on Ubuntu though, hence the need for mbstowcs

Comment: Should also note [this article](http://utf8everywhere.org) which is kind of an answer to Joel's article above.

Answer (score 0):

Here is [a little discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300804/wchars-encodings-standards-and-portability) I started a while ago on this subject.

Basically, I would personally distinguish two separate paths on encoding handling:

- One is an encoding-agnostic, "internally portable" path that using `mbstowcs` to convert the external multibyte data from `char * argv[]` and convert it into an internal, fixed-width wide string, all without ever talking about encodings.
- The other is a fixed-encoding, serializable path that deals with data that ships in deterministic encodings. To translate among those, the Posix `iconv` library does the trick.
- You can bridge between the two paths by using `iconv`'s special WCHAR_T encoding.

Since the situation that you describe requires you to read serialized, deterministic data, I would suggest using iconv to convert FROM UTF8 (which you know you have) and convert TO WCHAR_T, which you can then treat with your standard C wide string functions (but don't make assumptions about the actual encoding). If you need to print data to the console, you can always `wcstombs` from your internal wide strings to a multibyte representation (the details of which are again not of your concern) that the console told you it wants.

Comment: @R.: True; `printf("%ls")` will take care of the conversion for you. Good point.