# c++ convert from LPCTSTR to const char *

Tags: c++, types, type-conversion

I have this problem in MSVC2008 MFC. I´m using unicode. I have a function prototype:

```
MyFunction(const char *)
```

and I'm calling it:

```
MyfunFunction(LPCTSTR wChar).
```

> error:Cannot Convert Parameter 1 From 'LPCTSTR' to 'const char *'

How to resolve it?

Comment: What function are you calling? Did you write it yourself? Is it supposed to be capable of handling Unicode strings?

Answer (score 5):

Since you're using MFC, you can easily let CString do an automatic conversion from `char` to `TCHAR`:

```
MyFunction(CString(wChar));
```

This works whether your original string is `char` or `wchar_t` based.

**Edit:** It seems my original answer was opposite of what you asked for. Easily fixed:

```
MyFunction(CStringA(wChar));
```

`CStringA` is a version of `CString` that specifically contains `char` characters, not `TCHAR`. There's also a `CStringW` which holds `wchar_t`.

Answer (score 2):

`LPCTSTR` is a pointer to `const TCHAR` and `TCHAR` is `WCHAR` and `WCHAR` is most probably `wchar_t`. Make your function take `const wchar_t*` if you can, or manually create a `const char*` buffer, copy the contents, and pass that.

Comment: Even better, provide a generic translation function from `const wchar_t *` to `const char *` (or `std::wstring` to `std::string`) using locale-aware `wcstombs` and factor all your calls through that.

Comment: wcstombs is for :Convert const wchar_t * to char *. I have to convert from LPCTSTR(const wchar_t*) to const char*.

Comment: @Annie: `wcstombs` will work just fine. Any function that accepts a `const char *` will accept a `char *` too, it'll just treat the latter as if it were `const`.

Comment: @Annie: and where is the problem? If the function accepts a `const char *` it will accept without problems a `char *`.

Comment: Matteo: My problem is how to convert const wide char pointer to const single byte char pointer

Comment: @Annie: Make _two_ "conversion" functions, one serious one from `const wchar_t *`, and one dummy one taking a `const char *` returning immediately. With those two overloads, you can call your conversion function on a `TCHAR` no matter how that ends up being typedef'ed (it'll be either `char` or `wchar_t`.)

Answer (score 2):

When UNICODE is defined for an MSVC project `LPCTSTR` is defined as `const wchar_t *`; simply changing the function signature will not work because whatever code within the function is using the input parameter expects a `const char *`.

I'd suggest you leave the function signature alone; instead call a conversion function such as [`WideCharToMultiByte`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374130%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to convert the string before calling your function. If your function is called several times and it is too tedious to add the conversion before every call, create an overload `MyFunction(const wchar_t *wChar)`. This one can then perform the conversion and call the original version with the result.

Answer (score 2):

This may not be totally on topic, but I wrote a couple of generic helper functions for my proposed [wmain framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300804/wchars-encodings-standards-and-portability), so perhaps they're useful for someone.

Make sure to call `std::setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");` in your `main()` before doing any stringy stuff!

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <clocale>
#include <cassert>

std::string get_locale_string(const std::wstring & s)
{
  const wchar_t * cs = s.c_str();
  const size_t wn = wcsrtombs(NULL, &cs, 0, NULL);

  if (wn == size_t(-1))
  {
    std::cout << "Error in wcsrtombs(): " << errno << std::endl;
    return "";
  }

  std::vector<char> buf(wn + 1);
  const size_t wn_again = wcsrtombs(&buf[0], &cs, wn + 1, NULL);

  if (wn_again == size_t(-1))
  {
    std::cout << "Error in wcsrtombs(): " << errno << std::endl;
    return "";
  }

  assert(cs == NULL); // successful conversion

  return std::string(&buf[0], wn);
}

std::wstring get_wstring(const std::string & s)
{
  const char * cs = s.c_str();
  const size_t wn = mbsrtowcs(NULL, &cs, 0, NULL);

  if (wn == size_t(-1))
  {
    std::cout << "Error in mbsrtowcs(): " << errno << std::endl;
    return L"";
  }

  std::vector<wchar_t> buf(wn + 1);
  const size_t wn_again = mbsrtowcs(&buf[0], &cs, wn + 1, NULL);

  if (wn_again == size_t(-1))
  {
    std::cout << "Error in mbsrtowcs(): " << errno << std::endl;
    return L"";
  }

  assert(cs == NULL); // successful conversion

  return std::wstring(&buf[0], wn);
}
```

You could provide "dummy" overloads:

```
inline std::string get_locale_string(const std::string & s) { return s; }
inline std::wstring get_wstring(const std::wstring & s) { return s; }
```

Now, if you have an `LPCTSTR x`, you can always call `get_locale_string(x).c_str()` to get a `char`-string.

---

If you're curious, here's the rest of the framework:

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::wstring> parse_args_from_char_to_wchar(int argc, char const * const argv[])
{
  assert(argc > 0);

  std::vector<std::wstring> args;
  args.reserve(argc);

  for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
  {
    const std::wstring arg = get_wstring(argv[i]);
    if (!arg.empty()) args.push_back(std::move(arg));
  }

  return args;
}
```

Now the `main()` -- your new entry point is always `int wmain(const std::vector<std::wstring> args)`:

```
#ifdef WIN32

#include <windows.h>

extern "C" int main()
{
  std::setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");

  int argc;
  wchar_t * const * const argv = ::CommandLineToArgvW(::GetCommandLineW(), &argc);

  return wmain(std::vector<std::wstring>(argv, argv + argc));
}

#else // WIN32

extern "C" int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  LOCALE = std::setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");

  if (LOCALE == NULL)
  {
    LOCALE = std::setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "en_US.utf8");
  }

  if (LOCALE == NULL)
  {
    std::cout << "Failed to set any reasonable locale; not parsing command line arguments." << std::endl;
    return wmain(std::vector<std::wstring>());
  }

  std::cout << "Locale set to " << LOCALE << ". Your character type has "
            << 8 * sizeof(std::wstring::value_type) << " bits." << std::endl;

  return wmain(parse_args_from_char_to_wchar(argc, argv));
}

#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

In this example I convert a LPCTSTR to a const char pointer and a char pointer. For this conversion you need to include windows.h and atlstr.h, I hope to help you.

```
// Required inclusions
#include <windows.h>
#include <atlstr.h>

// Code
LPCTSTR fileName = L"test.txt";
CStringA stringA(fileName);
const char* constCharP = stringA;
char* charP = const_cast<char*>(constCharP);
```