# Converting char to wchar_t with less modification

Tags: c++, visual-c++, unicode, char, wchar

Currently my project does not support UNICODE. I want to make it to convert all the `char` to `wchar_t`.

My project has the mix of both `char` and `wchar_t`.

Basically one class I needed now to modify its arguments which is leading to more changes.
Kindly help how to make it will less changes.

Comment: You need to first of all understand and define what conversion you want to make. For starters you need to understand the encodings involved.

Comment: You can support unicode using `char` (consider utf8)

Answer (score 0):

You can Implement a Macro or inline function in a file which is common to whole project.
Macros should generally be avoided; prefer inline functions to them at all times, an inline function will respect namespaces and other scopes, as well as evaluating all the arguments once.

But for Macro Programming here is snippet

```
#define MACRO(X,Y) \
 ( \
  (cout << "1st arg is:" << (X) << endl), \
  (cout << "2nd arg is:" << (Y) << endl), \
  (cout << "3rd arg is:" << ((X) + (Y)) << endl), \
  (void)0 \
 )
```

For conversion logic refer

[How to convert char* to wchar_t*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032080/how-to-convert-char-to-wchar-t)