# Show glGetString output in message box

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, opengl, c++14

### My Code:

```
const wchar_t  *foo = reinterpret_cast<const wchar_t *>(glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION));
LPCTSTR sversion = foo;
MessageBox(NULL, sversion, TEXT("GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION"), MB_OK);
```

### The problem:

This results into some weird content of mostly Chinese and some other characters instead of the `GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION`, as the `reinterpret_cast` "interprets" the thing as something else as I've wanted it to. I've also tried to do it with normal C casts, but this results into the same problem and because glGetString returns an GLubyte* I cannot put the code directly into the MessageBox function as this requires an LPCTSTR as an input.

#### Note:

I've defined the `UNICODE` keyword in my files. This is why I am using `wchar_t` instead of `char`.

Comment: You can't randomly cast between `char*` as returned by `glGetString()` and `wchar_t*` willy-nilly like that. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032080/how-to-convert-char-to-wchar-t

Comment: Thats what I noticed. My problem is now, I want to display the output from glGetString in a windows message box, so how am I able to achieve this?

Comment: Just use `MessageBoxA` it will display ASCII in a Unicode application.  (`MessageBox` is a macro that maps to `MessageBoxW` or `MessageBoxA` depending on your unicode build settings.)