# Wide Char To Multi-Byte

Tags: windows, visual-c++, ofstream, wofstream

I'm trying to convert wide char into multi-byte.  It's only on yje myfile part.  The rest works fine.I can't use wofstream because I am using ofstream in several places, so I am left with this.

```
void PrintBrowserInfo(IWebBrowser2 *pBrowser) {
BSTR bstr;
pBrowser->get_LocationURL(&bstr);
std::wstring wsURL;
wsURL = bstr;

size_t DSlashLoc = wsURL.find(L"://");
if (DSlashLoc != wsURL.npos)
  {
  wsURL.erase(wsURL.begin(), wsURL.begin() + DSlashLoc + 3);
  }
  DSlashLoc = wsURL.find(L"www.");
  if (DSlashLoc == 0)
{
wsURL.erase(wsURL.begin(), wsURL.begin() + 4);
}
DSlashLoc = wsURL.find(L"/");
if (DSlashLoc != wsURL.npos)
{
wsURL.erase(DSlashLoc);
}
wprintf(L"\n   URL: %s\n\n", wsURL.c_str());
char LogURL = WideCharToMultiByte( CP_ACP, WC_COMPOSITECHECK, wsURL.c_str(), -1, NULL, 0,  NULL, NULL); 
    myfile << "\n   URL:" << LogURL;
    SysFreeString(bstr);
}

void EnumExplorers() {
CoInitialize(NULL);
SHDocVw::IShellWindowsPtr spSHWinds;
IDispatchPtr spDisp;
if (spSHWinds.CreateInstance(__uuidof(SHDocVw::ShellWindows)) == S_OK) {
    long nCount = spSHWinds->GetCount();
    for (long i = 0; i < nCount; i++) {
        _variant_t va(i, VT_I4);
        spDisp = spSHWinds->Item(va);
        SHDocVw::IWebBrowser2Ptr spBrowser(spDisp);
        if (spBrowser != NULL) {
            PrintBrowserInfo((IWebBrowser2 *)spBrowser.GetInterfacePtr());
            spBrowser.Release();
        }
    }
} else {
    puts("Shell windows failed to initialise");
}
```

}

Comment: What are you expecting to appear in `LogURL`? The return value of `WideCharToMultiByte` is the required size of the buffer. You need to take another read of the docs I think.

Comment: What is `wsURL`? Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587963/c-convert-from-lpctstr-to-const-char/6588525#6588525) may be useful.

Comment: I'm expecting LogURL to be a  URL sucj as "stackoverflow.com". See above for complete code.

Comment: wsURL is an URL such as stackoverflow.com

Comment: you declared LogURL as char. Can't fit a string in there. As I said, read the docs again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `WideCharToMultiByte` wrong. You need to pass it a string buffer to receive the converted string. Using `NULL` and `0` as parameters as you have done will return the required size of the result string.

```
int length = WideCharToMultiByte (CP_ACP, WC_COMPOSITECHECK, wsURL.c_str(), -1, NULL, 0,  NULL, NULL);
std::string LogURL(length+1, 0);
int result = WideCharToMultiByte (CP_ACP, WC_COMPOSITECHECK, wsURL.c_str(), -1, &LogURL[0], length+1,  NULL, NULL);
```

You should check `result` for a non-zero value to make sure the function worked correctly.

Comment: Thank you! It's returning the correct answer now.  Very good answer!