# How to convert Java String to C++ String using bytes as the medium

Tags: java, c++, string

What would be the algorithm/implementation of the C++ code `C++functionX` in the following flow chart:

```
(JavaString) --getBytes--> (bytes) --C++functionX--> (C++String)
```

`JavaString` contents should match `C++String` contents as far as possible (preferably 100% for all possible values of `JavaString`)

[EDIT] The endianness of bytes can be ignored as there are ways to handle that.

Comment: How is the Java string going to C++?  Via a file?

Comment: You mean something like from one programming language to another ?

Comment: @Mooing Duck: The java bytes are encoded base64 and transferred over the wire using XMPP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java:

```
String original = new String("BANANAS");
byte[] utf8Bytes = original.getBytes("UTF8");
//save the length as a 32 bit integer, then utf8 Bytes to a file
```

C++:

```
int32_t tlength;
std::string utf8Bytes;
//load the tlength as a 32 bit integer, then the utf8 bytes from the file
//well, that's easy for UTF8

//to turn that into a utf-18 string in windows
int wlength = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, utf8Bytes.c_str(), utf8Bytes.size(), nullptr, 0);
std::wstring result(wlength, '\0');
MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, utf8Bytes.c_str(), utf8Bytes.size(), &result[0], wlength);
//so that's not hard either
```

To do this in linux, one uses the iconv library, which is incredibly powerful, but more difficult to use.  Here's a function that converts a `std::string` in UTF8 to a `std::wstring` in UTF32: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=986a4a07e391213559d4e65acaf231d5-e54ee7a04e4b807da0930236d4cc94dc

Comment: I have to [object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300804/wchars-encodings-standards-and-portability) to that. `mbtowc` (I think you mean `mbstowcs`) has no notion of an explicit encoding. It's purpose is **not** to convert from UTF8. You really want to use a library that deals with explicit encodings, such as `iconv()`. The only purpose of the `mb/wc` functions in ANSI-C is to convert between `char` and `wchar_t`, *in a platform-dependent fashion*.

Comment: @Kerrek: I origionally had MultiByteToWideChar, but then found http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/mbstowcs/ when looking for something cross-platform

Comment: `mbstowcs` doesn't do what you claim. It's purpose is a different one. It may *work* in practice, but not because it's guaranteed to.

Comment: @Kerrek: I misread the docs.  I switched to OS-dependant code, but I've never worked with linux before, so that's just a guess.

Comment: @Mooing: OK - I wouldn't call `iconv()` that terribly OS dependent -- it's widely available, at *least* Posix and Windows. The crux is, one simply has to acknowledge that C++ doesn't have any built-in definite encoding handling in the standard, and so *any* such issue will require an encoding handling library. `iconv` is a very good choice.

Comment: @Kerrek: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconv  `Under Windows, the iconv binary (and thus, likely also the API) is provided by the Cygwin and GnuWin32 environments.`  I tend to think of things that don't support Linux/Windows as "OS dependant" and things that do both as "OS independent" even though I know it's not accurate :(

Comment: Mooing: I'm fairly sure I've seen standalone versions of `iconv` -- let me check, though, I guess this would actually be quite important to settle. *Edit.* Ah, [here we go](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libiconv.htm).

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as One True C++ String class. STL alone has `std::string` and `std::wstring`. That said, most string classes have a constructor that takes raw byte pointer as a parameter. The bytes come in the `const char *` form. So, a good example of your `C++functionX` is the constructor `std::string::string(const char*, int)`.

Note the encoding issues. getBytes() takes an encoding as a parameter; you better match that on the C++ side, or you'll get jumble. If not sure, use UTF-8.

Depending on what kinds of Java strings you have, you might want to choose either regular or wide strings (e. g. `std::wstring`). The latter is a slightly better representation of what Java String offers.

Comment: According to http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html, `A String represents a string in the UTF-16 format`, which is like `std::wstring` _sometimes_.  `std::wstring` is 16 bytes on Windows, but not Linux.

Comment: Depending on what the OP wants to do to his strings, and what's the nature of the content, a single-byte string in UTF-8 might do just as well. You'd be surprised how many text propcessing tasks are quite ASCII-friendly.

Comment: I don't know about the STL, but the C++ standard library has 4 string classes (all specializations of `std::basic_string`): `std::string`, `std::wstring`, `std::u16string`, and `std::u32string`. In this case, I think `std::u16string` would fit very nicely :)

Comment: @Mooing: 16 **bytes**?  That's one wide character.

Comment: depending on what he's doing he may run into endian issues with that, but it might be the best fit.

Comment: @Mooing duck: you can assume that I am handling endianness of bytes correctly.

Answer (score 1):

C++, as far as the standard goes, doesn't know about encodings. Java does. So, to interface the two, make Java emit some well-defined encoding, such as UTF8:

```
byte[] utf8str = str.getBytes("UTF8");
```

In C++, use a library such as `iconv()` to transform the UTF8-string either into another string of a well-defined encoding (e.g. `std::u32string` with UTF-32, if you have C++11, or `std::basic_string<uint32_t>` or `std::vector<uint32_t>` otherwise), or, alternatively, convert it to `WCHAR_T` encoding, to be stored in a `std::wstring`, and proceed further to convert this to a multi-byte string via the standard function `wcstombs()` if you wish to interface with your environment.

The choice depends on what you need to do with the string. For serialization or text processing, go with the definite encoding (e.g. UTF-32). For writing to the standard output using the system's locale, use the multibyte conversion. (Here is a [slightly longer discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300804/wchars-encodings-standards-and-portability) of encodings in C++.)

Answer (score 0):

the C++ string should probably be an std::wstring instance and you would alse need to keep track of the encoding you would use to transform from JavaString to bytes.

This article will probably help you more:

[std::wstring VS std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402283/stdwstring-vs-stdstring)