# Is there any built-in function that convert wstring or wchar_t* to UTF-8 in Linux?

Tags: c++, c, linux, utf-8, wstring

I want to convert wstring to UTF-8 Encoding, but I want to use built-in functions of Linux.

Is there any built-in function that convert `wstring` or `wchar_t*` to UTF-8 in Linux **with simple invokation**?

Example:

```
wstring str = L"file_name.txt";
wstring mode = "a";
fopen([FUNCTION](str), [FUNCTION](mode)); // Simple invoke.
cout << [FUNCTION](str); // Simple invoke.
```

Comment: What encoding are you assuming for wstring?

Comment: If you use std::string, and print that out to the console, the linux terminal,(at least on Ubuntu), will by default interpret it as utf-8.

Comment: @Darcy: well, this is true if the current locale is UTF-8, which is the default on most current Linux distributions, but it's not guaranteed.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: std::wstring on linux is always UTF-32 isn't it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The C++ language standard has no notion of explicit encodings. It only contains an opaque notion of a "system encoding", for which `wchar_t` is a "sufficiently large" type.

To convert from the opaque system encoding to an explicit external encoding, you must use an external library. The library of choice would be `iconv()` (from `WCHAR_T` to `UTF-8`), which is part of Posix and available on many platforms, although on Windows the [`WideCharToMultibyte`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374130(v=VS.85).aspx) functions is guaranteed to produce UTF8.

C++11 adds new UTF8 *literals* in the form of `std::string s = u8"Hello World: \U0010FFFF";`. Those are already in UTF8, but they cannot interface with the opaque `wstring` other than through the way I described.

[See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300804/wchars-encodings-standards-and-portability) for a bit more background.

Comment: C++11's utf-8 strings can interface with wstrings through `wstring_convert`

Comment: @Cubbi: I remain unconvinced that that has anything to do with UTF8. It looks like a mere wrapper for `wcstombs`. (There's a header `<cuchar>` that looks more promising.)

Comment: `wstring_convert` is not related to `wcstombs`. It's a wrapper for codecvt facets, such as `codecvt_utf8`.

Comment: @Kerreck SB: I think I see your point: except for the scant <cuchar> functions there is no portable connection between the C++03's generic narrow-multibyte/wide conversions and C++11's explicit UTF-8/UTF-16/UTF-16le/UCS2/UTF-32/UCS4 conversions. Interesting observation.

Answer (score 17):

If/when your compiler supports enough of C++11, you could use `wstring_convert`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <codecvt>
#include <locale>
int main()
{
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>> utf8_conv;
    std::wstring str = L"file_name.txt";
    std::cout << utf8_conv.to_bytes(str) << '\n';
}
```

tested with clang++ 2.9/libc++ on Linux and Visual Studio 2010 on Windows.

Comment: std::wbuffer_convert, std::wstring_convert, and the <codecvt> header (containing std::codecvt_mode, std::codecvt_utf8, std::codecvt_utf16, and std::codecvt_utf8_utf16) are deprecated in C++17. (The std::codecvt class template is NOT deprecated.)

Comment: @A.Danesh it was an aspirational deprecation, like with strstreams that were deprecated in C++98, but are still a mandatory part of C++20

Answer (score 1):

It's quite plausible that wcstombs will do what you need if what you actually want to do is convert from wide characters to the current locale.

If not then you probably need to look to ICU, boost or similar.

Comment: `wcstombs` has no notion of specific encodings. This is not the answer.

Comment: `wcstombs` should work if and only if the current locale is `UTF-8`.

Answer (score -1):

Certainly there is no function built in on Linux, because the name Linux references the kernel only, which doesn't have anything to with it. I seriously doubt that the libc that comes with gcc has such a function, and

```
$ man -k utf
```

supports this theory. But there are plenty of good UTF-8 libraries around. I personally recommend the iconv library for such conversions.

Comment: your man search lies to you: Linux glibc has an iconv implementation: http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/glibc-iconv-Implementation.html