# C store and print wchar_t

Tags: c, wchar-t

I want to store a string with characters from extend ascii table, and print them.
I tried:

```
wchar_t wp[] = L"Росси́йская Акаде́мия Нау́к ";
printf("%S", wp);
```

I can compile but when I run it, nothing is actually displayed in my terminal.

Could you help me please?

Edit:  In response to this comment:

```
wprintf(L"%s", wp);
```

Sorry, I forgot to mention that I can only use write(), as was only using `printf` for my first attempts.

Comment: Describe, *"nothing is happening"*?  Does your code compile? does it run?  Do other parts of the program work properly?

Comment: `wprintf(L"%s", wp);`

Comment: do `fflush(stdout);` afterwards.

Comment: > Describe, "nothing is happening"? My bad, I was a bit imprecise, I can compile but when I run it, nothing is actually displayed in my terminal. wprintf(L"%s", wp);
Sorry, I forgot to mention that I can only use write(), as was only using printf for my first attempts.

Answer (score 1):

If you want wide chars (16 bit each) as output, use the following code, as suggested by Michael:

```
wprintf(L"%s", wp);
```

If you need utf8 output, you have to use iconv() for conversion between the two. See [question 7469296](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469296/is-there-any-built-in-function-that-convert-wstring-or-wchar-t-to-utf-8-in-linu) as a starting point.

Comment: As I tell before i cant use wprintf, I have to reimplement %S option of printf with only  write and va_arg.

Comment: Then use iconv() to convert your wide string to UTF-8, and use write() to output it. (Assuming, that you need to create UTF-8 output).

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `setlocale()` first and use `%ls` in `printf()`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    // setlocale(LC_ALL, "C.UTF-8"); // this also works

    wchar_t wp[] = L"Росси́йская Акаде́мия Нау́к";
    printf("%ls\n", wp);

    return 0;
}
```

For more about `setlocale()`, refer to [Displaying wide chars with printf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40590207/displaying-wide-chars-with-printf/65975074#65975074)