# Lexicographical sorting for non-ascii characters

Tags: c++, sorting, non-ascii-characters, lexicographic

I have done lexicographical sorting for ascii characters by the following code:

```
std::ifstream infile;
std::string line, new_line;
std::vector<std::string> v;
while(std::getline(infile, line))
            {
                // If line is empty, ignore it
                if(line.empty())
                    continue;
                new_line = line + "\n";
                // Line contains string of length > 0 then save it in vector
                if(new_line.size() > 0)
                    v.push_back(new_line);
            }   
sort(v.begin(), v.end());
```

The result should be:
a 
aahr
abyutrw
bb
bhehjr
cgh
cuttrew
....

But I don't know how to do Lexicographical sorting for both ascii and non-ascii characters in the order like this: a A À Á Ã brg Baq ckrwg CkfgF d Dgrn... Please tell me how to write code for it. Thank you!

Comment: First you have to decide how you want to sort them. Does ‍♀️ come lexicographically before or after ☃? Write a function that carries out your decision.

Comment: @RaymondChen I want to make ascii comes before non-ascii characters. Non-ascii characters should follow the rule such as: `A, 'A, ^A, ~A...

Comment: In general, a `std::map` could be your solution (mapping the characters to the order index you intend). Then `std::sort` can be used with a custom predicate considering the order index for comparison. However, "`A" is not a character, these are two. Or did you mean "À"? Please, [edit] your question to clarify. (Give an example of the order, you prefer, involving non-ASCIIs.)

Comment: If you want to sort according to some specific locale, then you should use that locale for comparison. You need to know the encoding, the locale (language) and the operating system. The default locale "C" is usually only appropriate when you want to sort data for internal purpose (find data) but not to display data to user in alphabetical order of his own language except if data is limited to ascii characters (typically emails, url, postal code, identifier in some programming languages, etc would use only ascii characters)

Answer (score 2):

The OP didn't but I find it worth to mention: Speaking about non-ASCII characters, the encoding should be considered as well.

[**The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)**](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)

Characters like À, Á, and Â are not part of the [7 bit ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) but were considered in a variety of 8 bit encodings like e.g. [Windows 1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252). Thereby, it's not granted that a certain character (which is not part of ASCII) has the same code point (i.e. number) in any encoding. (Most of the characters have no number in most encodings.)

However, a unique encoding table is provided by the [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) containing all characters of any other encoding (I believe). There are implementations as

- [**UTF-8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) where code points are represented by 1 or more 8 bit values (storage with `char`)
- [**UTF-16**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) where code points are represented with 1 or 2 16 bit values (storage with `std::char16_t` or, maybe, `wchar_t`)
- [**UTF-32**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-32) where code points are represented with 1 32 bit value (storage with `std::char32_t` or, maybe, `wchar_t` if it has sufficient size).

Concerning the size of `wchar_t`: [Character types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types#Character_types).

Having that said, I used `wchar_t` and `std::wstring` in my sample to make the usage of umlauts locale and platform independent.

---

The order used in [`std::sort()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) to sort a range of `T` elements is defined by default with
`bool < operator(const T&, const T&)` the `<` operator for `T`.
However, there are flavors of `std::sort()` to define a custom predicate instead.

The custom predicate must match the signature and must provide a [strict weak ordering relation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/981299/7478597).

Hence, my recommendation to use a `std::map` which maps the charactes to an index which results in the intended order.

This is the predicate, I used in my sample:

```
  // sort words
  auto charIndex = [&mapChars](wchar_t chr)
  {
    const CharMap::const_iterator iter = mapChars.find(chr);
    return iter != mapChars.end()
      ? iter->second
      : (CharMap::mapped_type)mapChars.size();
  };

  auto pred
    = [&mapChars, &charIndex](const std::wstring &word1, const std::wstring &word2)
  {
    const size_t len = std::min(word1.size(), word2.size());
    // + 1 to include zero terminator
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
      const wchar_t chr1 = word1[i], chr2 = word2[i];
      const unsigned i1 = charIndex(chr1), i2 = charIndex(chr2);
      if (i1 != i2) return i1 < i2;
    }
    return word1.size() < word2.size();
  };

  std::sort(words.begin(), words.end(), pred);
```

From bottom to top:

1. `std::sort(words.begin(), words.end(), pred);` is called with a third parameter which provides the predicate `pred` for my customized order.
2. The lambda `pred()`, compares two `std::wstring`s character by character.
   Thereby, the comparison is done using a `std::map` `mapChars` which maps `wchar_t` to `unsigned` i.e. a character to its rank in my order.
3. The `mapChars` stores only a selection of all character values. Hence, the character in quest might not be found in the `mapChars`. To handle this, a helper lambda `charIndex()` is used which returns `mapChars.size()` in this case – which is granted to be higher than all occurring indices.

The type `CharMap` is simply a `typedef`:

```
typedef std::map<wchar_t, unsigned> CharMap;
```

To initialize a `CharMap`, a function is used:

```
CharMap makeCharMap(const wchar_t *table[], size_t size)
{
  CharMap mapChars;
  unsigned rank = 0;
  for (const wchar_t **chars = table; chars != table + size; ++chars) {
    for (const wchar_t *chr = *chars; *chr; ++chr) mapChars[*chr] = rank;
    ++rank;
  }
  return mapChars;
}
```

It has to be called with an array of strings which contains all groups of characters in the intended order:

```
const wchar_t *table[] = {
  L"aA", L"äÄ", L"bB", L"cC", L"dD", L"eE", L"fF", L"gG", L"hH", L"iI", L"jJ", L"kK", L"lL", L"mM", L"nN",
  L"oO", L"öÖ", L"pP", L"qQ", L"rR", L"sS", L"tT", L"uU", L"üÜ", L"vV", L"wW", L"xX", L"yY", L"zZ"
};
```

---

The complete sample:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

static const wchar_t *table[] = {
  L"aA", L"äÄ", L"bB", L"cC", L"dD", L"eE", L"fF", L"gG", L"hH", L"iI", L"jJ", L"kK", L"lL", L"mM", L"nN",
  L"oO", L"öÖ", L"pP", L"qQ", L"rR", L"sS", L"tT", L"uU", L"üÜ", L"vV", L"wW", L"xX", L"yY", L"zZ"
};

static const wchar_t *tableGerman[] = {
  L"aAäÄ", L"bB", L"cC", L"dD", L"eE", L"fF", L"gG", L"hH", L"iI", L"jJ", L"kK", L"lL", L"mM", L"nN",
  L"oOöÖ", L"pP", L"qQ", L"rR", L"sS", L"tT", L"uUüÜ", L"vV", L"wW", L"xX", L"yY", L"zZ"
};

typedef std::map<wchar_t, unsigned> CharMap;

// fill a look-up table to map characters to the corresponding rank
CharMap makeCharMap(const wchar_t *table[], size_t size)
{
  CharMap mapChars;
  unsigned rank = 0;
  for (const wchar_t **chars = table; chars != table + size; ++chars) {
    for (const wchar_t *chr = *chars; *chr; ++chr) mapChars[*chr] = rank;
    ++rank;
  }
  return mapChars;
}

// conversion to UTF-8 found in https://stackoverflow.com/a/7561991/7478597
// needed to print to console
// Please, note: std::codecvt_utf8() is deprecated in C++17. :-(
std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>> utf8_conv;

// collect words and sort accoring to table
void printWordsSorted(
  const std::wstring &text, const wchar_t *table[], const size_t size)
{
  // make look-up table
  const CharMap mapChars = makeCharMap(table, size);
  // strip punctuation and other noise
  std::wstring textClean;
  for (const wchar_t chr : text) {
    if (chr == ' ' || mapChars.find(chr) != mapChars.end()) {
      textClean += chr;
    }
  }
  // fill word list with sample text
  std::vector<std::wstring> words;
  for (std::wistringstream in(textClean);;) {
    std::wstring word;
    if (!(in >> word)) break; // bail out
    // store word
    words.push_back(word);
  }
  // sort words
  auto charIndex = [&mapChars](wchar_t chr)
  {
    const CharMap::const_iterator iter = mapChars.find(chr);
    return iter != mapChars.end()
      ? iter->second
      : (CharMap::mapped_type)mapChars.size();
  };
  auto pred
    = [&mapChars, &charIndex](const std::wstring &word1, const std::wstring &word2)
  {
    const size_t len = std::min(word1.size(), word2.size());
    // + 1 to include zero terminator
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
      const wchar_t chr1 = word1[i], chr2 = word2[i];
      const unsigned i1 = charIndex(chr1), i2 = charIndex(chr2);
      if (i1 != i2) return i1 < i2;
    }
    return word1.size() < word2.size();
  };
  std::sort(words.begin(), words.end(), pred);
  // remove duplicates
  std::vector<std::wstring>::iterator last = std::unique(words.begin(), words.end());
  words.erase(last, words.end());
  // print result
  for (const std::wstring &word : words) {
    std::cout << utf8_conv.to_bytes(word) << '\n';
  }
}

template<typename T, size_t N>
size_t size(const T (&arr)[N]) { return sizeof arr / sizeof *arr; }

int main()
{
  // a sample string
  std::wstring sampleText
    = L"In the German language the ä (a umlaut), ö (o umlaut) and ü (u umlaut)"
      L" have the same lexicographical rank as their counterparts a, o, and u.\n";
  std::cout << "Sample text:\n"
    << utf8_conv.to_bytes(sampleText) << '\n';
  // sort like requested by OP
  std::cout << "Words of text sorted as requested by OP:\n";
  printWordsSorted(sampleText, table, size(table));
  // sort like correct in German
  std::cout << "Words of text sorted as usual in German language:\n";
  printWordsSorted(sampleText, tableGerman, size(tableGerman));
}
```

Output:

```
Words of text sorted as requested by OP:
a
and
as
ä
counterparts
German
have
In
language
lexicographical
o
ö
rank
same
the
their
u
umlaut
ü
Words of text sorted as usual in German language:
ä
a
and
as
counterparts
German
have
In
language
lexicographical
o
ö
rank
same
the
their
u
ü
umlaut
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6283efec5af9ec0a)

**Note:**

My original intention was to do the output with `std::wcout`. This didn't work correctly for ä, ö, ü. Hence, I looked up a [simple way to convert `wstring`s to UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7561991/7478597). I already knew that UTF-8 is supported in coliru.

---

[@Phil1970](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58886724/lexicographical-sorting-for-non-ascii-characters/58890922?noredirect=1#comment104048966_58890922) reminded me that I forgot to mention something else:

Sorting of strings (according to “human dictionary” order) is usually provided by `std::locale`. [`std::collate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/collate) provides a locale dependent lexicographical ordering of strings.

The locale plays a role because the order of characters might vary with distinct locales. The [`std::collate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/collate) doc. has a nice example for this:

```
Default locale collation order: Zebra ar förnamn zebra ängel år ögrupp
English locale collation order: ängel ar år förnamn ögrupp zebra Zebra
Swedish locale collation order: ar förnamn zebra Zebra år ängel ögrupp
```

Conversion of UTF-16 ⇔ UTF-32 ⇔ UTF-8 can be achieved by mere bit-arithmetics. For conversion to/from any other encoding (ASCII excluded which is a subset of Unicode), I would recommend a library like e.g. [libiconv](https://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/).

Comment: Seriously, **you don't want to define your own sort function**! It does not handle all languages and one can easily forget some less known rules or characters. One should almost always prefer a sort from a library. For ex. how want should handle oe, œ, oé, ôé, ôe, oè etc. In French, for example, the comparison without diacritic is done forward and then the diacritic are compared in backward order. Also rules might get improved over time (for ex. sort in Windows file explorer now know hot to sort number like **picture 9** before **picture 10**). Otherwise, lot of useful think in that answer.

Comment: @Phil1970 You're correct. I forgot that I wanted to mention `std::locale::collate` as well. Sorting of numbers (e.g. in Explorer) has always amused me. Actually, I don't need this. If I want to have files sorted I give it resp. names (with leading 0s in case). ;-)