# Python embedded : How to pass special characters to PyRun_SimpleFile

Tags: python, c++, python-embedding

Consider the following code running embedded Python script from C++. It create an embedded Python module with a function that will report current file/line upon execution.

```
#include <Python.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

PyObject * mymodule_meth_test(PyObject * self) {
    PyTraceBack_Here(PyEval_GetFrame());
    PyObject * exc;
    PyObject * val;
    PyObject * tb;
    PyErr_Fetch(&exc, &val, &tb);
    PyTraceBack_Print(tb, PySys_GetObject("stderr"));
    
    std::cout << "LINE is " << PyLong_AsLong(PyObject_GetAttrString(PyObject_GetAttrString(tb, "tb_frame"), "f_lineno")) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "FILE is " << PyUnicode_AsUTF8(PyObject_GetAttrString(PyObject_GetAttrString(PyObject_GetAttrString(tb, "tb_frame"), "f_code"), "co_filename")) << std::endl;

    Py_RETURN_NONE;
}

PyMethodDef module_methods[] = {
    {"test", (PyCFunction)mymodule_meth_test, METH_NOARGS, NULL},
    {},
};

PyModuleDef module_def = {PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT, "mymodule", NULL, -1, module_methods};

extern "C" PyObject * PyInit_mymodule() {
    PyObject * module = PyModule_Create(&module_def);
    return module;
}
    
void runScript( const std::string& script, bool utf8 )
{
    Py_SetPythonHome( L"C:\\dev\\vobs_sde\\sde\\3rdparty\\tools_ext\\python\\Python38" );

    PyImport_AppendInittab("mymodule", &PyInit_mymodule);

    // Initialize the Python Interpreter
    Py_Initialize();

    FILE* file = NULL;
    open(&file,script);
    if ( file )
    {
        wchar_t* sScriptUTF8 = Py_DecodeLocale(script.c_str(), NULL);
        if ( PyRun_SimpleFile(file, (utf8) ? (const char*) sScriptUTF8 : script.c_str()) == 0 )
            std::cout << "SUCCESS" << std::endl;
        else
            std::cout << "FAIL" << std::endl;
        fclose(file);
    }
    
    Py_Finalize();
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    std::fstream file2;
    file2.open( "mainéfile.py", std::ios_base::out );
    file2 << "import mymodule" << std::endl;
    file2 << "mymodule.test()" << std::endl;
    file2.close();

    std::cout << std::endl << "Will fail to execute script" << std::endl;
    runScript( "mainéfile.py", false );
    std::cout << std::endl << "Will work! But FILE will be reported as 'm' instead of 'mainéfile.py'" << std::endl;
    runScript( "mainéfile.py", true );
    
    return 0;
}
```

This script outputs:

```
Will fail to execute script
FAIL
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 4: invalid continuation byte

Will work! But FILE will be reported as 'm' instead of 'mainéfile.py'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "m", line 2, in <module>
LINE is 2
FILE is m
SUCCESS
```

So, as you can see:

- If I pass the regular `char*` "mainéfile.py" to `PyRun_SimpleFile` it fails to run the script.
- If I pass the `wchar_t` "mainéfile.py" string to `PyRun_SimpleFile`, it is able to run the script, but then file nam reported by `mymodule_meth_test` is `m` while `mainéfile.py` is expected.

This is likelly because, as `wchar_t`, "mainéfile.py" is "'m', 0, 'a', 0,..." and this is later interpreted as a regular `char*` becoming then "m" because second item is considered as EOS.

How should I invoke `PyRun_SimpleFile` to have this work correctly?

---

Note, I ended up being able to call `PyRun_SimpleFile` as below:

```
std::string utf8Str = std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>>().to_bytes(Py_DecodeLocale(script.c_str(), NULL));
if ( PyRun_SimpleFile(file, utf8Str.c_str()) == 0 )
    std::cout << "SUCCESS" << std::endl;
else
    std::cout << "FAIL" << std::endl;
```

However, later in `mymodule_meth_test` call to `PyUnicode_AsUTF8` will return `NULL` and I could not find out how to correctly retrieve the file name...