# How to check if a string has valid UTF-8 characters in C++?

Tags: c++, utf-8

I am trying to use [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/) libraries to test if a string has invalid UTF-8 characters.  I created a UTF-8 converter but no invalid data gives me an error on conversion. Appreciate your help.

Thanks,
Prashanth

```
int main()                                                                                        
{                                     
    string str ("AP1120 CorNet-IP v5.0 v5.0.1.22 òÀ MIB 1.5.3.50 Profile EN-C5000");
    //  string str ("example string here");
    //  string str (" ����������"     );                  
    UErrorCode status = U_ZERO_ERROR;                   
    UConverter *cnv;            
    const char *sourceLimit;    
    const char * source = str.c_str();                  
    cnv = ucnv_open("utf-8", &status);                                                              
    assert(U_SUCCESS(status));                                                                      

    UChar *target;                                                                                  
    int sourceLength = str.length();                                                                
    int targetLimit = 2 * sourceLength;                                                             
    target = new UChar[targetLimit];                                                                

    ucnv_toUChars(cnv, target, targetLimit, source, sourceLength, &status);
    cout << u_errorName(status) << endl;
    assert(U_SUCCESS(status));                          
}
```

Comment: Not familiar with this library but seems to me if you open your converter with `"utf-8"` and then call `ucnv_toUChars` to convert aren't you more or less telling it to convert from Unicode to Unicode? It may short circuit with success in this case. I'd try opening it with a iso encoding or something else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I modified your program to print out the actual strings, before and after:

```
#include <unicode/ucnv.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    std::string str("22 òÀ MIB 1");
    UErrorCode status = U_ZERO_ERROR;
    UConverter * const cnv = ucnv_open("utf-8", &status);
    assert(U_SUCCESS(status));

    int targetLimit = 2 * str.size();
    UChar *target = new UChar[targetLimit];

    ucnv_toUChars(cnv, target, targetLimit, str.c_str(), -1, &status);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i != targetLimit && target[i] != 0; ++i)
        std::printf("0x%04X ", target[i]);
    std::cout << std::endl;
    for (char c : str)
        std::printf("0x%02X ", static_cast<unsigned char>(c));
    std::cout << std::endl << "Status: " << status << std::endl;
}
```

Now, with default compiler settings, I get:

```
0x0032 0x0032 0x0020 0x00F2 0x00C0 0x0020 0x004D 0x0049 0x0042 0x0020 0x0031
0x32 0x32 0x20 0xC3 0xB2 0xC3 0x80 0x20 0x4D 0x49 0x42 0x20 0x31
```

That is, the input **is already UTF-8**. This is a conspiracy of my editor that saved the file in UTF-8 (verifiable in a hex editor), and of GCC that sets is *execution character set* to UTF-8.

You can coerce GCC to change those parameters. For example, forcing the execution character set to ISO-8859-1 (via `-fexec-charset=iso-8859-1`) produces this:

```
0x0032 0x0032 0x0020 0xFFFD 0xFFFD 0x0020 0x004D 0x0049 0x0042 0x0020 0x0031
0x32 0x32 0x20 0xF2 0xC0 0x20 0x4D 0x49 0x42 0x20 0x31
```

As you can see, the input is now ISO-8859-1-encoded, and the conversion prompty *fails* and produces "invalid character" code points U+FFFD.

However, the conversion operation still returns a "success" state. It appears that the library doesn't consider a user data conversion error an error of the function call. Rather, the error status seems to be reserved for things like running out of space.

Comment: Interesting, my guess was somewhat close then. +1 for experimenting. I was about to come back with a post saying `ucnv_getInvalidUChars` may be more what the OP wants but it may be better in your answer, if applicable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it now makes sense why conversion wasn't failing. For testing purposes if I want to continue to use the default character set of gcc, is it possible to save the input in such a way that it is saved in its original form and not in the UTF-8 form?

Comment: @user1245457: There's no input in the example, only hardcoded data in the source code. Nothing happens to the actual *input*, which is just an opaque byte stream and which you can save at will.

Comment: @KerrekSB - if I continue to use the default character set of gcc, how do I detect an non-UTF8 input?  regardless of the input string, if the default character set is used, all input strings are flagged as valid

Comment: You don't. Rather, you write in your manual, "the input must be encoded in UTF-8". Input is just a sequence of dumb numbers, and if you don't agree on what they mean, you can't just guess. The better solution would be to use the environment's locale setting (see `<locale>`), and do the whole `mbsrtowcs`- followed by iconv-WCHAR-to-UTF8 conversion [that I keep going on about](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300804/wchars-encodings-standards-and-portability)...

Comment: @KerrekSB, I just ran your example above for the Chinese character: 斯 and this is my output: first line: 0x65AF  second line: 0xE6 0x96 0xAF It looks like the second line is UTF-8 but what is the first? Is it UTF-16? Thank you!

Comment: @CarolineBeltran: Wouldn't that depend on your source and execution character sets, and your editor?

Comment: I'm Using VC++ 2013 and saving the source file using Notepad++ in UTF-8 format.  I'm just confused as to the format being used by VC++ 2013 when encountering std::string str("斯");

Comment: @CarolineBeltran: You need to ask your editor, or look at your source file in a hex editor. I can't possibly know :-(

Comment: @KerrekSB, I found a site that converts strings to both UTF-8/16 and converted the Chinese character that I mentioned above and got the same results produced by your code snippet.  This was really helpful to me because I can see that even though I hardcode a character into VC++ 2013 and save the source file as UTF-8, VC++ will still treat the hardcoded strings as UTF-16.  I've never used a Linux compiler but from what I've read, I'd think that a Linux user would never have this issue.

Answer (score -1):

I use this code. I detect all charsets for my string and test one by one if charsetname == "UTF-8". True is valid UTF-8 breaks the loop and finally return the result, False if no charsets found or chatsetnames not equals to "UTF-8".

**References**

[ICU documentation ChatsetDetector](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/conversion/detection.html#charsetdetector)

**Code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unicode/ucsdet.h>

#define UTF8_CHARSET_NAME_STRING ("UTF-8"s)

using namespace std::string_literals;

bool IsValidUTF8(const std::string &data)
{
    UErrorCode status = U_ZERO_ERROR;
    UCharsetDetector *detector = ucsdet_open(&status);
    ucsdet_setText(detector, data.c_str(), data.length(), &status);
    int32_t detectedNumber = 0;
    auto matches = ucsdet_detectAll(detector, &detectedNumber, &status);
    if (!matches)
    {
        return false;
    }
    bool valid = false;
    for (int32_t i = 0; i < detectedNumber; i++)
    {
        const char *charsetName = ucsdet_getName(matches[i], &status);
        if (UTF8_CHARSET_NAME_STRING == charsetName)
        {
            valid = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    ucsdet_close(detector);
    return valid;
}

int main()
{
    String strData = {(char)0xff, 0x25, 0x00, (char)0xfa, (char)0xff,(char)0xff,(char)0xff}; 
    std::cout<< "Result: " << (IsValidUTF8(strData)? ("true; Original String : \"" + strData + "\"") : "false") <<std::endl;  
    
    strData = "HelloWorld!!!";    
    std::cout<< "Result: " << (IsValidUTF8(strData)? ("true; Original String : \"" + strData + "\"") : "false") <<std::endl;                        
    return EXIT_SUCCESS; // 0
}
```

**Output**

[image: output]

```
Result: false
Result: true; Original String : "HelloWorld!!!"
```