# How to use wcstombs instead of WideCharToMultiByte ？

Tags: c++

`wcstombs` have three args.

`WideCharToMultiByte` have eight args.，

How to replace？

How use `wcstombs` write like that :

```
int kk = WideCharToMultiByte(936, 0, szBn, ccBn+1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

How use `wcstombs` write like that :

```
int kk= WideCharToMultiByte(936,
                            0,
                            szBn,
                            ccBn+1,
                            kkburr,
                            (ccBn+1)*sizeof(wchar_t),
                            0,
                            0)
```

Does it same?

Comment: Not the same thing, you can't specify a locale or codepage with wcstombs(), you only get the default locale.  What are you *really* trying to do?

Comment: Maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300804/wchars-encodings-standards-and-portability) of mine is of some interest for you.

Comment: The WideCharToMultiByte code is run on Pc. Then I want to run the code on Mac ,so I need to Remove the WideCharToMultiByte，because it not run on Mac.

Comment: @cuichang: Not possible to do that with an one-liner.

Answer (score 3):

[`WideCharToMultiByte`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) does something **much different** than `wcstombs`, so it's at least somewhat doubtful¹ that this replacement would be successful.

Specifically, WCTMB converts from UTF-16 to another character set (and encoding) of your choice. [`wcstombs`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/wcstombs/) converts from a "wide character string" to a "multibyte string", but the standard leaves the exact definition of these terms to the implementor.

In other words: WCTMB converts from a known encoding to another known encoding. `wcstombs` converts from an unknown encoding to another unknown encoding. You cannot replace the former with the latter, especially if you want to convert to a Chinese encoding (isn't that what 936 is?).

What's the reason for seeking to do this replacement? Whatever it may be, it's almost certain that there are more appropriate ways to achieve the goal.

**Update:** If you want a platform-independent, reliable solution then I 'd recommend [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/). Don't expect to find an one-line replacement for WCTMB because it simply doesn't exist.

---

¹ massive understatement

Answer (score 0):

- The resulting encoding that `wcstombs` converts to depends on the current locale while `WideCharToMultiByte` can be explicitly given a codepage.
- `wcstombs` converts from "wide character string", which encoding depends on the implementation of the standard library. `WideCharToMultiByte` converts from the string in UTF-16. Wide characters `wcstombs` rely upon may not be encoded in UTF-16, but in Windows wide characters are UTF-16.
- `wcstombs` is portable, `WideCharToMultiByte` is not. If your target platform is Windows only then it doesn't matter.
- `WideCharToMultiByte` allows to specify a "default character" which will be used instead of characters that can't be represented in target encoding.

So `WideCharToMultiByte` is much more powerful and is probably used as a backend for `wcstombs`.

If your current codepage is not 936, then the replacement you ask about is impossible.

Comment: @cuichang It must. Just try it!

Comment: `wcstombs(kkburr, szBn, ccBn)`. It requires the wide-character string `szBn` to be zero-terminated, and the target string `szBn` to be at least `ccBn+1` bytes long.