# How to search for text in wide string obtained from wstringstream

Tags: c++, unicode, substring, stdstring

I have a stream of words that give me a word in each run of the loop as `std::string`. But ideally this should be `std::wstring`. So after I obtain the string I convert it to `std::wstring`. This I input into a `std:wstringstream`. Finally, after all words from the stream are processed,and then I convert the `std:wstringstream` into a `std::wstring`, and then search for the required term (originally a `std::wstring`) in it. This is my code:

```
while (stream)
{
    std::string word = stream->getWord();
    boost::trim(word);    

    std::wstring longWord(word.length(), L' '); // Make room for characters
    std::copy(word.begin(), word.end(), longWord.begin());

    fMyWideCharStream << longWord;
    stream->next();
}

std::wstring fContentString = fMyWideCharStream.str();

size_t nPos = fContentString.find(fSearchString, 0); //fSearchString is std::wstring

while(nPos != std::wstring::npos)
    {
        qDebug() << "Pos: " << nPos << endl;
        nPos = fContentString.find(fSearchString, nPos+1);
    }
```

I have this string: **Passive Aggressive Dealing With Passive Aggression, Lost Happiness & Disconnection Copyright © 2014**, where the **©** is a wide character. As `std::string` it takes up two positions. As `std::wstring` it takes 1, which is what I want. However, on trying `fSearchString` with a value of `L"2014"`, I am still getting a value of 96, whereas it should be 95 since this string is now `std::wstring`.

Any idea what I should do to fix this?

Comment: As an aside, your two-line copy is almost equivalent to `std::wstring longWord(word.begin(), word.end());`

Comment: Oh, yup, you are right. :)

Comment: Have you tried the `std::wstring::find` method?

Comment: Calling `find` on a `std::wstring` will invoke that automatically, I presume?

Comment: @Cupidvogel `std::wstring::find` is invoked *exactly* by calling `find()` on a `std::wstring`

Comment: Yes, thought so. Then why the above comment by @ThomasMatthews?

Comment: Are you sure that the contents of `fContentString` match what is in your question?  If I just copy your string and call `find()` it works [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c78c6703f2905fbb)

Comment: Have you checked that `std::copy(word.begin(), word.end(), longWord.begin());` does what you think it does? Since `std::copy` is a general purpose algorithm, it seems unlikely that it will suddenly decide to invoke a multibyte-to-wide-character conversion.

Comment: @Cupidvogel: Sorry, I was going by your question's title on *"How to search..."*.  Looks like your question is not about searching.

Comment: @NathanOliver, yes I know it will work in a direct string. The problem is how to make it work from the stream.

Comment: @rici, I found this here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6691597/1469954

Comment: Which compiler do you use? It is definitely wrong to convert string to wstring this way if the original string contains anything except ASCII (e.g. UTF8 characters).

Comment: We are using clang..

Comment: @Cupidvogel: That code only widens characters. It does not do multibyte to wide character conversion.

Comment: Oh, okay then. How do I do it then?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19649192/1553090

Comment: By the way, why do you call `stream->next();` twice in the loop? Is it not a mistake?

Comment: No no, that is a typo here, it works fine in my actual code. Editing it.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the original `string` is not ASCII-only - it contains multibyte character '©', it is wrong to convert from `string` to `wstring` using character-by-character conversion. Therefore both

```
std::wstring longWord(word.length(), L' '); // Make room for characters
std::copy(word.begin(), word.end(), longWord.begin());
```

and

```
std::wstring longWord(word.begin(), word.end());
```

do not work for a `string` containing multi-byte characters.
To properly convert from multibyte-character `string` to `wstring` on Windows you could use mbstowcs(): http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/mbstowcs/

In a platform-independent way, with C++11 (compile options to clang: `-std=c++1` ) you can do this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14809553/1915854 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/18597384/1915854

Example if you need characters beyond what a single wchar_t can store:

```
std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> converter;
std::wstring longWord = converter.from_bytes(word);
```

If you don't need characters beyond what a single wchar_t can store:

```
std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>> converter;
std::wstring longWord = converter.from_bytes(word);
```

Necessary includes:

```
#include <locale>
#include <codecvt>
#include <string>
```

There seem used to be other options prior to C++11 in Boost.

Comment: I assume U16 and U8 refer to `std::wstring` and `std::string` respectively? What compiler options do I need to provide?

Comment: @Cupidvogel, I've updated my answer with code example particular to your case. Please, try.

Comment: So this will ensure that the `wstringstream` truly consists of long words. Will converting it to `std::wstring` through the `str()` method keep it safe?

Comment: What do you mean by "keeping it safe"? I expect that `str()` method of `wstringstream` returns a `wstring` containing what was in the `wstringstream`.

Comment: Yep, yep, I mean that only. Gonna try it now.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks! One more question, I haven't has the opportunity of testing it out in Windows yet, will this work on Windows as well for sure?

Comment: @Cupidvogel, on Windows I am getting e.g. std::range_error exception in case the `string` is not UTF-8, but in some ASCII code page e.g. Windows-1251 (Cyrillic).

Comment: In my case, the words obtained are guaranteed to be `std::string`. Will there be a problem, then?

Comment: If the `std::string` contains UTF-8 characters, there should be no problem. But if the string is in ASCII code page, you can get `std::range_error` exception. I don't know for sure, thus you can ask another question if something is still not clear to you.